# commandline works, same command in Makefile doesn't

Tags: c++, command-line, makefile

I went through [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Mesa-%28OpenGL%29-on-Linux-Mint) tutorial on how to install Mesa(OpenGL). Everything works as described. But when I try to put the build command, which works perfectly, into a makefile it doesn't.

This is my makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -lglut -IGL -IGLEW -IGLU main.c -o OpenGLExample
```

If I enter make, I get:

```
gcc -lglut -IGL -IGLEW -IGLU main.c -o OpenGLExample
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glColor3f'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glOrtho'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glBegin'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glEnd'
/tmp/ccKVrQAu.o:main.c:function renderFunction: error: undefined reference to 'glFlush'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm using Ubuntu instead of Mint as in the tutorial.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised that the first invocation worked. You have to put the `-lXXX` linker flags at the end of the command line.

Comment: @H2CO3 Or at least after any of the source files which use them.  (I think you can put the `-I` options after the `-l` with no problem.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass OpenGl libraries to the linker. Instead of `I` you should type `l`:

```
all:
    gcc main.c -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU  -o OpenGLExample
```

You should also pass directory where your compiler can find OpenGL header files, this can be done with `-I`, and probably also an option (or options) specifying where the linker should look for the libraries `(-L)`.

Comment: You may also have to pass an option (or options) specifying where the linker should look for the libraries (`-L`).